# jquery mmenu how to hide the navbars dynamically

Tags: jquery, mmenu

When user clicks `<a>` in the `<li>`, I want the script to hide the `navbars`. How to do that?

```
navbars: [
  {
    position: 'top',
    content: ['<div>.........</div>']
  },
  {
    position: 'bottom',
    content: ['<div>.........</div>']
  }
]
```

---

```
.on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function (e) {
  //do  some thing here 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `display:none;` to the navbars class, For example, if your navbar container class is .navbar, then the statement would look like as,

```
                          $(".navbar").css("display", "none");
```

Put in inside your function, as given above, and you're done. The complete code will be,

```
 .on('click',
                    'a[href^="#"]',
                    function (e) {
                        $(".navbar").css("display", "none");
                    }
                );
```

For more info on css method visit - [jQuery css() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_css.asp)

Answer (score 0):

close, but this will work,

```
$(".navbar").css("display", "none");
```